# Firebase Plugin installed failed in cordova android

Tags: android, firebase, extjs, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': Error: Uh oh!

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/hda_admin/Projects/App/platforms/android/app/src/main'
    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1210:3)
    at mayCopyFile (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:59:8)
    at onFile (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:54:10)
    at getStats (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:48:44)
    at startCopy (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:38:10)
    at handleFilterAndCopy (/Users/hda_admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:33:10)
    at Object.copySync (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:26:10)
    at copyFile (/Users/admin/Projects/App/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:223:12)
    at install (/Users/admin/Projects/App/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:61:13)
    at ActionStack.process (/Users/admin/Projects/App/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ActionStack.js:56:25)
```

Uh oh!
EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/admin/Projects/App/platforms/android/app/src/main'

Cordova version : 10.0.0

Cordova android : 9.0.0

Already tried this solution also : [Ionic error : Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': Error: Uh oh - while installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449369/ionic-error-failed-to-install-cordova-plugin-firebase-error-uh-oh-while)

it won't work for me. If any other solution?